# Must complete atomless Boolean algebras of the same cardinality be isomorphic?

Tags: boolean-algebra

More generally: must complete Boolean algebras of the same cardinality and with the same cardinality of atoms be isomorphic?

Comment: The answer to your "more general" question is an easy no. A complete BA is the sum of a complete atomic BA and a complete atomless BA. Two complete BAs may have the same number of atoms, but one may be atomic and the other nonatomic; or they may both be nonatomic, but have different size atomless parts. The answer to the title question is also no but I'll let an expert on BAs answer it.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I misformulated the general principle I was interested in -- I intended an additional same-cardinality requirement on atomless elements.  But I see that, since complete BA's can be factored into a complete atomic BA and a complete atomless BA, the general question I intended is equivalent to the titular one.

Answer (score 1):

No. The quotient of the Boolean algebra $B$ of Borel subsets of $[0,1]$ by the ideal of meager (=  first Baire category) sets and the quotient of the same $B$ by the ideal of sets of Lebesgue measure zero are both atomless, and they both have the cardinality of the continuum, but they are not isomorphic.  Specifically, the latter satisfies a weak distributive law that fails in the former.

Comment: Or in other words: Cohen is not Random. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila To finish translating my answer into the language of forcing, the last sentence says that random is $\omega^\omega$-bounding and Cohen isn't.

Comment: Yes, I figured that would have been the weak distributive law. But "Cohen is not Random" is a nice statement that will confuse everyone who is not a set theorist.